# delete file every 60 days using java logger

Tags: java, logging

I have to create a file using logger in java and i have to delete automatically only the content that was written before 60 days- not all the file!!
how can I manage the delete of the rows using the logger abilities?

i read about DailyRollingFileAppender but i don't know how to use it in order to delete the old logs.anyone know i can i use it?

Comment: Can you add the code you wrote and the problem you are actually facing?

Comment: Deleting a segment of the beginning of a huge file is an inefficient operation. You shouldn't try to do this. Why don't you just use what the rest of the world is using, which is Rolling File Appenders?

Comment: would it be easier to create a log file for each day and delete the files older than 60 days?

Comment: just an alternative solution to OPs problem...not saying it is the best

Comment: @orangegoat What your describe takes *zero* lines of code: it's a standard configurable option in all logging frameworks.

Comment: what is the configuration?

Comment: is java.util.logging.Logger configuration support this mechanism?